# Directory owner is a number instead of a name in Centos. Why is that?

Tags: centos, permissions, uid

I am using Centos and I did ll command for one of the directory. Owners of the files within the directory are some numbers instead of username. Can you please explain why is that ?

If you see below instead of root as the owner, it is showing 600 as the owner. And there is no user called as 600. Why is that ?

```
-rw-rw-r-x.  1  600 root 1696 Jun 27  2016 abc.txt
-rw-rw-r-x.  1  600 root 1696 Jun 27  2016 xyz.txt
-rw-rw-r-x.  1  600 root 1692 Jun 27  2016 hagts.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

My first assumption is that you, or someone, as root, tried to change permissions on the directory or files therein with something like

```
# chmod 600 *
```

but mistyped as

```
# chown 600 *
```

This will change the owner to `600`.  This is a valid operation even if there is no such user on the system.  The files will be owned by UID 600 (which may be unassigned).

To change them back, use

```
# chown dave *
```

as root (replace `dave` with your username).

You may want to pick specific files and directory names instead of `*` if you don't want to affect all files and directories. You should also retrace your steps by looking in the shell history to see what you *actually* did to change the ownership (if it was you).

Another possibility is that the files and their ownership were transferred from another machine where UID 600 *is* a valid user. This can easily happen if the files are residing on a network share and the users on the current machine are not synced in any way with the machine that created the files.

You may change the ownership with `chown` as root still.